# Classes for acquiring employee information

Tags: java, homework

I'm looking for a review on the following classes and the comments I applied (class assignment):

```
package assignment1;

/**
 * Returns a GeneralEmployee object
 * Sets the name, id for the object when called.
 * It increments the id that is assigned to a new employee object so that each employee gets a unique id
 * It can be used to compare if another GeneralEmployee object is equal
 * @author me
 *
 */
public abstract class GeneralEmployee implements Employee {

    private String name;
    private static int initialId = 0;
    private int id;

    /**
     * Sets name to passed name param
     * Increments initialID by 1
     * sets id to value of intialId
     * @param name
     */
    public GeneralEmployee(String name) {
        super();
        this.setName(name);
        initialId++;
        id = Integer.valueOf(initialId);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the name of the emloyee
     * @return
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the name of the employee
     * @param name
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the id of the employee
     * @return
     */
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /*
     * Returns a String comprising the name, id and pay of the employee
     */
    public String toString() {
        return "name " +  getName() + " id " + getId() + " pay " + getPayCheckAmount();
    }

    /*
     * Returns true if the GeneralEmployee object passed to it is equal to the current GeneralEmployee object
     */
    public boolean equals(Object anOject){
        GeneralEmployee generalEmployee;
        try {
            generalEmployee = (GeneralEmployee) anOject;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
        return generalEmployee.id==id;
    }

}


package assignment1;

/**
 * This class extends GeneralEmployee
 * It is used to set and get the hoursWorked and calculate payCheckAmount based on hoursWorked 
 * @author me
 *
 */
public class PartTimeEmployee extends GeneralEmployee{

    private double hoursWorked;
    private double hourlyPayRate;

    /**
     * Set name and hourly rate of employee
     * @param name
     * @param hourlyPayRate
     */
    public PartTimeEmployee(String name, double hourlyPayRate) {
        super(name);
        this.hourlyPayRate = hourlyPayRate;             
    }

    /* 
     * Return payCheckAmount by checking if hoursWorked > 40
     * If hoursWorked greater then 40 then calculate regular pay plus overtime pay
     * If hoursWorked is not greater then just calculate regular pay     * 
     * @return payCheckAmount
     */
    @Override
    public double getPayCheckAmount() {

        double payCheckAmount;

        if(hoursWorked > 40){            
            payCheckAmount = (40 * hourlyPayRate) + ((hoursWorked - 40) * (1.5 * hourlyPayRate));
        }
        else{
            payCheckAmount = hoursWorked * hourlyPayRate;
        }

        return payCheckAmount;
    }

    /**
     * Return hoursWorked
     * @return hoursWorked
     */
    public double getHoursWorked() {

        return hoursWorked;
    }

    /**
     * Set hoursWorked
     * @param hoursWorked
     */
    public void setHoursWorked(double hoursWorked){
        this.hoursWorked = this.hoursWorked + hoursWorked;
    }
}


package assignment1;

/**
 * Runnable class that will create 5 employees, setting their name, hourlyPayRate and hoursWorked and to return the payCheckAmount based 
 * on those set values
 * 
 * Also checks to see if any employees have a duplicate id
 * 
 * @author me
 *
 */
public class Driver {

    /**
     * Used to start program
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String args[]){

        PartTimeEmployee employee1, employee2,employee3,employee4,employee5;

        // working over 40 hours
        employee1 = new PartTimeEmployee("bob", 5);
        employee1.setHoursWorked(8);        
        employee1.setHoursWorked(8);
        employee1.setHoursWorked(8);
        employee1.setHoursWorked(8);
        employee1.setHoursWorked(10);
        System.out.println(employee1.toString());

        // working under 40 hours
        employee2 = new PartTimeEmployee("cindy", 5.5);
        employee2.setHoursWorked(0);        
        employee2.setHoursWorked(0);
        employee2.setHoursWorked(10);
        employee2.setHoursWorked(10);
        employee2.setHoursWorked(0);
        System.out.println(employee2.toString());   

        // working 40 hours
        employee3 = new PartTimeEmployee("fred", 6);
        employee3.setHoursWorked(8);        
        employee3.setHoursWorked(8);
        employee3.setHoursWorked(8);
        employee3.setHoursWorked(8);
        employee3.setHoursWorked(8);
        System.out.println(employee3.toString());

        // working over 4 hours
        employee4 = new PartTimeEmployee("jim", 6.5);
        employee4.setHoursWorked(8);        
        employee4.setHoursWorked(8);
        employee4.setHoursWorked(8);
        employee4.setHoursWorked(10);
        employee4.setHoursWorked(10);
        System.out.println(employee4.toString());

        // working 0 hours
        employee5 = new PartTimeEmployee("lucy", 7);
        employee5.setHoursWorked(0);        
        employee5.setHoursWorked(0);
        employee5.setHoursWorked(0);
        employee5.setHoursWorked(0);
        employee5.setHoursWorked(0);
        System.out.println(employee5.toString());

        Employee employees[] = new Employee[]{employee1,employee2,employee3,employee4,employee5};

        // call method to check if any of the created employees have a duplicate id
        checkIfEmployeeIdIsDuplicate(employees);

    }

    /**
     * @param employees
     * @return true if a duplicate id is found for PartTimeEmployee
     */
    private static boolean checkIfEmployeeIdIsDuplicate(Employee employees[]){

        if(employees!=null){
          for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
              for (int j = 0; j < employees.length; j++) {
                  Object object1 = employees[i];
                  Object object2 = employees[j];
                  if (object1 != null && object2 != null && i!=j) {
                      PartTimeEmployee DuplicateEmployeeId1 = (PartTimeEmployee)object1;
                      PartTimeEmployee DuplicateEmployeeId2 = (PartTimeEmployee)object2;
                      if (DuplicateEmployeeId1.equals(DuplicateEmployeeId2)) {
                          System.out.println(DuplicateEmployeeId1.toString() + " equals name " + DuplicateEmployeeId2.toString());
                      }
                  }
              }
          } 
        }

        return false;

    }

}

package assignment1;

/**
 * interface used for making sure there is a method to return the payCheckAmount
 * @author me
 *
 */
public interface Employee {
    public double getPayCheckAmount();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Just a couple of small points:

**Constructor: setting fields**

The general style of setting fields in a constructor looks like this:

```
this.name = name;
```

instead of `this.setName(name);`. Generally, it is good to use methods once they are defined, but in the case of a constructor, it is better to just set the field directly. If you use a setter, the setter might be overridden by a subclass, and then bugs could be introduced.

**Integer `valueOf` integer**

You don't need to call `id = Integer.valueOf(initialId);`. `initialId` is already an integer, so just do `id = initialId`.

**`@Override`**

If you override a method, add the `@Override` annotation, this makes your code easier to read. For example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
```

**equals**

Use `instanceof` instead of a `try-catch` block, it will be faster.

**Magic Numbers**

Do not hardcode numbers like `40` or `1.5`. Store it in a field instead, and give that field a good name. That way, if you need to change the value, you only need to change it in one place, and also the reader will know what eg `40` represents.

**`checkIfEmployeeIdIsDuplicate`: deeply nested & bug**

The `checkIfEmployeeIdIsDuplicate` method never returns true, this seems like a bug.

Also, the method is very deeply nested. To fix this, first of all use an early return like this:

```
if(employees == null){
    return true; // or throw exception
}
```

**`checkIfEmployeeIdIsDuplicate`: unnecessary cast & another bug**

Why store `employees[i]` as an `Object`, and then cast it to `PartTimeEmployee`? Just store it as `PartTimeEmployee` directly. Either way, if it is not a `PartTimeEmployee`, but a different kind of employee, this will cause an error.

Then, there wouldn't really be the need to store it, so your code could look like this:

```
private static boolean checkIfEmployeeIdIsDuplicate(Employee employees[]) {
    if (employees == null) {
        return true; // or throw exeption
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < employees.length; j++) {
            if (employees[i] != null && employees[j] != null && i != j && employees[i].equals(employees[j])) {
                System.out.println(employees[i].toString() + " equals name " + employees[j].toString());
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It still always returns false though (except if null is passed).

**Naming**

It is customary to use camelCase in Java, so for example `DuplicateEmployeeId1` should be `duplicateEmployeeId1`. But it is not actually an id, so it should be `duplicateEmployee1`, or just `employee1` (we don't even know yet if it is a duplicate).

Comment: Thanks very much for all the suggestions.  I have implemented most of what you indicated.

Answer (score 3):

You should work on your comments. Why do you say that the class "Returns a GeneralEmployee object"? A method *returns* something, a class *represents* it.
The comment on the constructor looks quite redundant. What does it add in addition to what is already written in the code?

I think you should try to write self-esplicative code and limit comments to explain the reasons why you did something in that way or something that is particularly obscure. There is no point in repeating what it is already clear from the source code.

Talking about the actual code, do you really need to change the values of `name` and `id`? I'd rather make that class immutable, which has a lots of advantage in terms of ease of understanding the code and in term of maintaining it.

Why do you have `id = Integer.valueOf(initialId);`? Isn't `id=initialId` equivalent and more readable? I cannot see a reason why you want to do that.

Are you sure that id generation it should be responsibility of the `GeneralEmployee` class? I think it would be much better to have a separate `IdGenerator` class, with a `NextId()` method and call it from outside the constructor and then pass to the constructor of `GeneralEmployee` the computer identifier. In that way you will have separate classes that address different concerns.

I see you defined `equals` but not `hashCode`. In general it is better to define both of them. [Here you can find more details](http://www.xyzws.com/javafaq/why-always-override-hashcode-if-overriding-equals/20).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  Very helpful.  
id = Integer.valueOf(initialId); was a leftover that from earlier work that I forgot to simplify.  The overuse of comments is because the instructor for the courst that I am taking indicates that he would like everything commented.  As for creating a separate IdGenerator, I am not allowed to as it is not part of the spec.

Answer (score 3):

1. **General comment regarding comments**

   You should always stick with the Javadoc-style of comments for your methods, because I can see some of them are just multi-line comments. I hope it is just accidental deletes on that extra `*` on the first line.
2. **`Employee` Interface**

   Would you consider adding a method `addHoursWorked(double hoursWorked)` to your `Employee` interface, since, they are supposed to be working...? :p

   The reason I suggest using a prefix other than `set` is because that usually implies (or at least to me) you are over-riding whatever existing values that method is for, which is why this chunk of code was confusing to look at first:

   ```
   employee4.setHoursWorked(8);
   employee4.setHoursWorked(8);
   employee4.setHoursWorked(8);
   employee4.setHoursWorked(10);
   employee4.setHoursWorked(10);
   ```
3. **`GeneralEmployee` abstract class**

   In your case, you don't have to call `super()`. As suggested by @tim, you can simply set `id` as such:

   ```
   id = ++initialId; // prefix ++ to increment *before* assignment to id
   ```

   The `equals()` method can be implemented in the <s>simpler</s> more terse form below:

   ```
   public boolean equals(Object anOject){
       return anObject instanceof GeneralEmployee && ((GeneralEmployee) anObject).id == id;
   }
   ```

   Finally, as suggested by @mariosangiorgio, you should over-ride `hashCode()` too, and I'll leave you with this one <s>weird</s> tip: `hashCode()` returns an `int`, your `id` is both an `int` and used for testing equivalence in your `equals()` method, so...
4. **`PartTimeEmployee` implementation**

   Inside your `getPayCheckAmount()`, you can consider using a conditional operator (i.e. `? :`) to perform and return the calculation in one step. Without showing you the full code, here's something to start you off with:

   ```
   return hoursWorked > 40 ? /* calculate for >40 hrs */ : /* calculate for <=40 hrs */;
   ```

   Instead of writing `this.hoursWorked = this.hoursWorked + hoursWorked` in full, you can simply write `this.hoursWorked += hoursWorked`.
5. **`Driver` class**

   You can consider having a method that helps you create a new `PartTimeEmployee` and add the number of hours worked. This eliminates the code repetition you have currently. For example:

   ```
   private static Employee createPartTimeEmployee(final String name, double hourlyPayRate, double... hoursWorked) {
       PartTimeEmployee employee = new PartTimeEmployee(name, hourlyPayRate);
       for (double current : hoursWorked) {
           employee.addHoursWorked(hoursWorked);
       }
       return employee;
   }

   // usage
   PartTimeEmployee employee1 = createPartTimeEmployee("bob", 5, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10);
   ```

   `System.out.println()` works with `Object`s too, by calling their `toString()`. So, you can simply write `System.out.println(employee1)`.

   Finally, are you allowed to use Java Collections classes in your homework assignment, or is that something reserved for the future? If I can use those classes, what I may want to do is to use a `HashMap` (and this is where over-riding the `hashCode()` method is relied upon) to store the `toString()` representations of the `employees` iterated through, with their `id`s as the key of the map. If the map already contains an existing value, I know that there has been a duplicate. How that is handled is up to your assignment...

Comment: In response to #2, your comments made me look back at the assignment and I now notice that it only calls for me to put in the hours for the week, not for each day.  Thanks.

In response to #5, I have to stick with the UML diagram that was provided in the class and cannot add any additional methods to the classes.